Prove a four-velocity vector lies inside of the light cone; do I just need to prove that the four-velocity is a timelike vector?
New to relativity; and I'm reading the Hartle books, on page 144;

The questions asks to show that, at every point along the curve $x_s(t)$, the four-velocity of the ship lies inside the forward light cone. (assume $c=1$)
From my understanding, we need to prove that
(1) the four velocity $\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{u}= g_{\alpha\beta}\mathbf{u}^{\alpha}\mathbf{u}^{\beta} =-1 $
(2) $\frac{dt}{d\tau} = \mathbf{u}^t > 0$
But I have doubt on (1); because it seems to that (1) is always true regardless of the choice of metric $g$ and the curve $x_s(t)$ because
$$g_{\alpha\beta}\mathbf{u}^{\alpha}\mathbf{u}^{\beta}  = g_{\alpha\beta} (\frac{d\mathbf{x}(t)^{\alpha}}{d\tau})(\frac{d\mathbf{x}(t)^{\beta}}{d\tau})$$
where $\mathbf{x}(t)$ is the curve
The definition of proper time is
$$d\tau^2 = -g_{\alpha\beta} (d\mathbf{x}(t)^{\alpha})(d\mathbf{x}(t)^{\beta})$$
Therefore, substitute the above equation into earlier one.
$$g_{\alpha\beta}\mathbf{u}^{\alpha}\mathbf{u}^{\beta}  = g_{\alpha\beta} (\frac{d\mathbf{x}(t)^{\alpha}}{d\tau})(\frac{d\mathbf{x}(t)^{\beta}}{d\tau}) = - \frac{d\tau^2}{d\tau^2} = -1$$
So, regardless of the curve $\mathbf{x}(t)$ and the choice of metric $g$; we will always have the four-velocity vector at point $p$ (vector that tangent to $p$) has magnitude of -1. But this seems not correct, because we can have a world-line nearly parallel to horizontal x-axis (in this case, we have $y,z$ position unchanged, so just imagine the $tx$ plane); its tangent vector will be nearly parallel to x-axis (where light ray has slope 1).
For this question, the function $f(r_s)$ clearly plays vital role here, but I don't know how to use to to solve the problem
Am I missing anything here?
==========================================
EDIT UPDATE
So we're showing that $ds^2 < 0$
$$ds^2 = -dt^2 + (dx - V_s(t)f(r_s)dt)^2$$
Expanding
$$ds^2 = -dt^2 + dx^2 + V_s(t)^2f(r_s)^2dt^2 - 2V_s(t)f(r_s)dtdx$$
Since $V_s(t) = \frac{dx_s(t)}{dt} \implies dx_s(t) = V_s(t)dt$; we can change $dx$ to $V_s(t)dt$
$$ds^2 = dt^2(-1 + V_s(t)^2 + V_s(t)^2f(r_s)^2 - 2V_s(t)^2 f(r_s) )$$
$$ds^2 = dt^2(-1 + (V_s(t) - V_s(t)f(r_s))^2)$$
$$ds^2 = dt^2[V_s^2(t)(1-f(r_s))^2-1]$$
Clearly; since $f(r_s) = 1$ when $r_s=0$ and decrease as $r_s$ gets larger and vanishing if $r_s > R$ for some fixed $R$ ($r_s = (x-x_s(t)^2 + y^2 + z^2$ just the usual
Euclidean distance from the curve), we have $0<(1-f(r_s))^2<1$, then $ds^2 < 0$ if $V_s(t) < 1$ (ship travelling slower than the speed of light).
However, we can have $V_s(t) > 1$ at some region of the curve $x_s(t)$; in that case, we must have $(1-f(r_s))^2$ very close to zero; which means $r_s$ is close to or on the curve.
We can conclude that, given this curve ( the worldline of the ship); when the ship appears travelling faster than the speed of light for some region (such as shown in the picture below, the region inside the rectangular); $V_s(t) > 1$, but within a very neighborhood of that region (grey shaded region); within this region, $r_s$ is close to the curve enough that $V_s^2(t)(1-f(r_s))^2 < 1$; hence, in this neighborhood, $ds^2 < 0$ and the ship is within the light cone.  I guess this grey shaded region is what we called the "bubble" in sci-fic ? For any observers outside of this spacetime region, they see ship travelling faster than the speed of light.

A follow-up question:
In the shade region, the light cone are different inside and outside of the shade region. It appears that the light of speed is faster in the shaded region than the light of speed outside of the region ? Will the observers in the flat spacetime (outside of the shade region) have two different measurement of the light speed? (he measures the speed of light travelling at outside region $c_1$, the standard speed of light ($299,792,458 m/s$), then, he (as an observer still outside the region) measures the speed of light travelling inside the region, $c_2$; he would have $c_1< c_2$ ? I guess the observers live within the region would measure the light speed travelling inside the region to be $c_1$)

You have as the definition of proper time that it satisfies the equation
$$
d\tau^2 = -g_{\alpha\beta} (d\mathbf{x}(t)^{\alpha})(d\mathbf{x}(t)^{\beta})
$$
for all infinitesimally separated points along the worldline.  But for this quantity $\tau$ to be a well-defined quantity, it's required that the right-hand side of this equation is positive at all points along the worldline.
If it's not, we don't really have a well-defined four-velocity vector in the first place.  Remember that the signal property of a four-velocity vector is that it is a unit timelike vector that is tangent to the worldline.  In contrast, you can write down a curve in spacetime whose tangent is always spacelike, and so a proper time for the curve doesn't exist.  The point of Hartle's problem is therefore to prove that $ds^2 = - d\tau^2 < 0$ (and therefore that $\tau$ exists) for all infinitesimally separated points along the given worldline.
As an example of what could go wrong, consider the curve
$$t = u, x = 2 u, y = z = 0$$
in flat spacetime.  The separation between two infinitesimally separated points along the worldline is
$$
ds^2 = -(du)^2 + (2 du)^2 + 0 + 0 = 3 du^2
$$
which is always positive.  So we can't even define a proper time for this curve in the first place.
[Aside:  there is an analogous parameter we can define for spacelike & lightlike curves, called a affine parameter. It doesn't have the nice physical meaning that we can associate with the proper time, but it can be useful, particularly for light rays.  Take a look back at Section 5.5 for how it pops up there, and why we can't define a proper time for light rays either.]

Thanks for the comment. I've just updated my post to include my understanding to the problem. Can you give a check to see if I'm understanding it correctly ?

Your calculations look basically correct, though I did not look over them in detail.  As far as the follow-up question goes, you should ask it as a new question.


So, regardless of the curve x(t)
and the choice of metric g
; we will always have the four-velocity vector at point p
(vector that tangent to p
) has magnitude of -1.

Ha its correct.Hoping my English would not be confusing.
First,the norm of 4-velocity is indeed a scalar on the spacetime manifold,so it should not depend on the choice of coordinate system.
And if we don't consider 4-force,the norm clearly should stay the same.So if in one coordinate system its 1 or 2,it will remain 1 or 2 respectively.

So, regardless of the curve x(t)
and the choice of metric g
; we will always have the four-velocity vector at point p
(vector that tangent to p
) has magnitude of -1

We know in genral $u^μ=(γ,γv^x,γv^y,γv^z)$,if we consider the rest observer we have $\gamma =1$ and $v^i=0$ so $u^\mu=(1,0,0,0)$ and its norm become -1.
